# What is the point of the X509Store Constructor (String)?

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509

It seems as though you can set up a valid `X509Store` object based on any string.
eg.

```
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("abcdef")
```

I originally was using

```
 $store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("Cert:\CurrentUser\My")
```

thinking I had a valid object for the `My` store, however I kept getting an exception when calling:

```
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::MaxAllowed) #Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect.
```

Is the string meant to be in a certain format?

EDIT:
It seems as though the string can be anything, as long as there are no slashes. So I need to use `$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("My")`.

Comment: Have a look at [MSDN - X509Store Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In particular constructor parameters "Name" and "Location". Seems like valid locations include: "CurrentUser" and "LocalMachine". Your original "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" is in PowerShell format. I would omit the  "Cert:\" PS drive.

Comment: Based on the last comment $store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("My", "CurrentUser") should work.

Comment: but that constructor takes two parameters. I'm asking about the one string parameter constructor.

Comment: I do get that, that comment was more in line with your other question.

Comment: What other question? I want to know how to get access to the "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" store using the constructor with one string parameter. I don't want to use the two parameter constructor.

Comment: $store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("My")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting [MSDN X509Store Class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here is the gist of my understanding of it.

There are a number of constructors for X509Store Class. After defining an instance of the class, this can then be opened using the Open method.

If the instance points to a valid StoreName in a valid StoreLocation the Open method will open a certificate store. The Open method can also create a new store based on flags [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags] used, if the StoreLocation is correct.

If the store instance is not defined correctly, open method it will generate a System.ArgumentException.

Valid StoreLocation values are

- CurrentUser
- LocalMachine

and valid StoreName values are

- AddressBook
- AuthRoot
- CertificateAuthority
- Disallowed
- My
- Root
- TrustedPeople
- TrustedPublisher.

This is what MSDN has to say about the (String) constructor.

"Use this constructor to create an X509Store object using a particular X.509 store name for the **current user**. To create a new store, specify a name that does not exist. A new store will be created with that name."

So this code should create a new certificate store in "CurrentUser" called "abcdef".

```
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("abcdef")
$openFlags = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::MaxAllowed
$store.Open($openFlags)
```

It can be verified using MMC.

[image: New certificate store]

So, in conclusion, store constructor parameters "StoreName" and "String" are interchangeable. Semantically "StoreName" is used in reference to predefined values and "String" can refer to any value.

Comment: so are you saying that $store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("abcdef") will create  new store called abcdef? If I want to open this store, how would I do it? The Open() method doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. I have updated the answer with code I have tested. If this doesn't work for you, what error do you get?

Comment: ok, but the original question was "does the string need to be in a certain format?". From a few tests, it seems as though the only condition is that the string does not contain any slashes. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. There may be more characters that cause issues. As the string is equivalent to certificate store name, restrictions will be in line with x509certificate store name restrictions. Unfortunately I still have not found a reference for this.

Comment: Have a look at [RFC 2459 - Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure ](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2459.txt). Don't have time ATM to go through it all, but from Appendix C: "_The character string type PrintableString supports a very basic Latin character set:  the lower case letters 'a' through 'z', upper case letters 'A' through 'Z', the digits '0' through '9', eleven special characters ' " ( ) + , - . / : ? and space_" I assume that special characters are not allowed in the Cert Store name and will cause issues.

Comment: So if using a string for StoreName targeting one of the enumerated StoreNames like "TrustedPeople", I'm assuming this string must match the name of enumerated field "TrustedPeople", NOT the name as seen in the Microsoft Management Console | Certificates which shows "Trusted People" (note the space).  Is that assumption correct?